# How to deploy meteor app to DigitalOcean

Tags: meteor, github, ssh, deployment, digital-ocean

I created a new app repository in Github, built on the Meteor platform. I am having significant difficulty deploying the app to my DigitalOcean droplet, however. I am trying to connect my Github repository to the droplet and to deploy that to my domain. I am trying to do this in SSH using puTTy; however, after setting up a root account and password, I am unable to log in through SSH. I receive the following error: [disconnected: no supported authentication methods available (server sent:publickey)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AM0sP.png)

Does anyone know why this error is coming up? I have looked through more tutorials for deploying a meteor app on digitalocean than I care to admit, but they all seem to take different approaches and many are outdated. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-log-into-your-droplet-with-putty-for-windows-users?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://guide.meteor.com/deployment.html#custom-deployment

Comment: Following this thread, because I am looking for a simple way to deploy my meteor app.   Please update if you find a simple way to do a deploy because I've spent all day  and no luck!

Answer (score 1):

I reckon the easiest way is to use meteor up. It's a very simple process, and you don't need to be continually sshing into your target server, with all the hassles involving ssh keys.

In my experience, once you have it set up, it's a very painless process, and you can deploy with a simple command each time.

http://meteor-up.com/

It looks after the following:

- Setting up your server with docker instances
- Creating SSL certs using Let's encrypt
- Building your app, bundling it, transferring it
- Starting the app
- Rolling back if it doesn't work

There is some trust involved, but it's worth it for a seamless deployment scenario